# C# how to fill xml file with string value

Tags: c#, xml, string

For example, my string is:

```
<Here>
<Hey>smth</Hey>
<Hi>else</Hi>
</Here>
```

I want my document x.xml to have that content. I tried

```
xmlDoc.InnerXml = thatString;
```

but it throws an exception.

Comment: What XML document are you trying to produce? If it's not valid XML, you can't use XML code (duh!).

Comment: **What exception do you get**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
XElement here = XElement.Parse("<Here><Hey>smth</Hey><Hi>else</Hi></Here>");
```

Then to save it to a file.

```
here.Save("filePath");
```

Answer (score 1):

XmlDocument.LoadXml

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

even better - use linq to xml.  i prefer the XDocument class of XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

I beleive your code is for reading only. You have to use `XmlTextWriter` instead.